# How can I fix MySQL storage overhead issue?

Tags: mysql

**When I am creating new `field` after `198` columns, MySQL show below Error**

------------------**MySQL ERROR:**------------------

> #1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

*Note*: I already changed datatypes `VARCHAR` -> to `TEXT` -> to `TINYTEXT`

I found many results for this Question in `StackOverflow`. Some people suggested to use `TEXT` instead of `VARCHAR`. But it works for upto `100` or `120` fields. Actually i need maximum `500` fields for my MySQL table.

------------------**My TABLE NAME : `dynamic_fields`**------------------

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | field_1 | field_2 |  ....   |   ....  |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |  NULL   |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I am adding fields to table `dynamic_fields` dynamically from **PHP** script.

Now `dynamic_fields` table have **198** fields with datatype `TINYTEXT`

------------------**SCENARIO:** for `dynamic_fields` fields------------------

Datatype `TINYTEXT` holds memory 256 bytes.
Memory `256` bytes for every fields.
Fields `198`.
Total Memory : `256`*`198` = 50688 bytes.

I need maximum `500` fields for `dynamic_fields`

**NOTE:** I am using `InnoDB` storage Engine for `MySQL`

How can I fix this error? Or is there any way to increase storage size for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding fields after fields to a table, you can store the `entity_id`, the `field_name`, the `field_value` and optionally the `field_order` in your table:

```
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| id | entity_id | field_name | field_value |  field_order  |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
|  1 | 1         | field_1    | NULL        | 1             |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
|  2 | 1         | field_2    | NULL        | 2             |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
|198 | 1         | field_198  | NULL        | 198           |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Doing so you will be able to add as many fields as you want for your entities. Instead of one row for each entity, you'll have as many rows as fields for each entity.

If the field in question is null you can skip recording it, and when retrieving the values of your entity set `null` for the missing fields (in which case the lines in my example wouldn't exist).

Comment: Probably this is a good solutions. But this table have too many rows. And all reports will generate from this table. If i follow this solution, Then the report generation will be  slow process.

Comment: As I suggested, you can record only not null fields, resulting in less rows. You might want to test this solution before discarding it ;)

Comment: But this table will hold maximum 500+ new fields. And everyday `10,000+` rows will upload in this table. It is big deal with big data. Ok, I will follow this solution, After testing i will inform here, it is working perfectly or not. Thank you!

Comment: After doing your solution how can i get `field_name` as Column Name? Can you give me the query please?

Comment: If you want to retrieve to value of a field named `my_column_name` (for example), you can use `SELECT field_value FROM my_table WHERE field_name = "my_column_name" AND entity_id = 123;`

Comment: Thank you! But actually i want `field_1`,`field_12`,...`field_198` as Column.

Comment: It's up to you to give whatever name you want in `field_name`. To retrieve all the columns of an entity, just request it like that: `SELECT field_name, field_value FROM my_table WHERE entity_id = 123;`  you'll retrieve all the fields associated with your entity, with their name (`field_1`, `field_2`, ..., `field_198`) and their values.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I will try.

Comment: I accepted your answer. But your solution is `very slow` when generating reports. I am using my another solution for this problem. Anyway thanks :) @Veve

Answer (score 1):

As mysql say:

> The maximum row length, except for variable-length columns (VARBINARY, VARCHAR, BLOB and TEXT), is slightly less than half of a page for 4KB, 8KB, 16KB, and 32KB page sizes. For example, the maximum row length for the default innodb_page_size of 16KB is about 8000 bytes. For an InnoDB page size of 64KB, the maximum row length is about 16000 bytes. LONGBLOB and LONGTEXT columns must be less than 4GB, and the total row length, including BLOB and TEXT columns, must be less than 4GB.
>   (reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

So you will need to increase `innodb_page_size`. Which is in some terms related to `innodb_buffer_pool_size` ... so probably you should also consider increasing this option also.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` - defines how much memory is allocated for mysql to cache the data from data tables and indexes. Increasing of `innodb_page_size` means that you would have less rows cached in memory (if you don't change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value)

But I would advise you to go for different table structure - for example use multiple tables - instead of increasing the `innodb_page_size`

Comment: This table already related with more 3 tables. If I increase `innodb_page_size`, Is there any problem?

Comment: Probably not.  But you have to consider increasing in `innodb_buffer_pool_size`